# Grid System not working as expected with DomPdf

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-4, dompdf

I am using [DomPdf](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf)
to generate a PDF from blade file which has two tables in the same row. When i display the blade as a webpage it appears as expected but when I convert it to PDF each table appears in single row.

What I want:
[image]

What I got:

[image]

this is my blade code of the two tables:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-sm" >
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row" style="width: 15%"><strong>Assigment No.:</strong></th>
                        <td>
                            FICT-ASSIGN-202207034356
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row" style="width: 15%"><strong>Period No.:</strong></th>
                        <td>
                            1
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row" style="width: 15%"><strong>Number of Pages:</strong></th>
                        <td>
                            1
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-xl">
        <div class="table-responsive" >
            <table class="table table-bordered table-sm">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row"><strong>Client:</strong></th>
                        <td>
                            First International for Consults & Training
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row"><strong>Address:</strong></th>
                        <td>
                            Office #1, Floor #1, Building #11, Ibn Seena St #10, Al Muntazah #1
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row"><strong>City:</strong></th>
                        <td>
                            Doha
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row"><strong>Phone No.:</strong></th>
                        <td>
                            (+974) 4444 4444
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row"><strong>Email:</strong></th>
                        <td>
                            info@example.com
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I used `col-` `col-xs` `col-xl` none of them worked fine.

this is how i generate the PDF:

```
public function getPdf()
{
    $t = $this->generateAssignPDF();
    return $t->stream();
}

private function generateAssignPDF()
{

    $pdf = app('dompdf.wrapper');
    $pdf = $pdf->loadView('pdf_temps.assign_card')
    ->setPaper('a4', 'portrait');
    return $pdf;
}
```

I'm using:

Laravel v9

PHP v8.1.5

Bootstrap v4.1.3

DomPdf v2

Comment: try 'landscape' instead of 'portrait'..

Comment: @HonkderHase same problem

Comment: My buest guess then: HTML render engine of DomPdf can't cope with the styles in the same way as your browser does. You could try to reduce data in all cells to a minimum to see, if tables still wrap around.

Comment: @HonkderHase i did as you suggested but still same

Comment: Hi, use @media print {.table-responsive > table{width:50%}}, hope this should fix your issue.

Comment: @MohammedYousuff didn't work too

Answer (score 1):

finally, an idea popped to my mind to include the two tables in one table and it worked as expected

here is my code:

```
<table class="table table-borderless" >
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 50%; padding:0%;">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-borderless table-sm" >
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row" style="width: 30%"><strong>Assigment No.:</strong></th>
                                <td>
                                    FICT-ASSIGN-202207034356
                                </td>
    
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row"><strong>Period No.:</strong></th>
                                <td>
                                    1
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row"><strong>Number of Pages:</strong></th>
                                <td>
                                    1
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div> 
            </td>
            <td style="width: 50%; padding:0%;">
                <div class="table-responsive" >
                    <table class="table table-borderless table-sm">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row" style="width: 20%"><strong>Client:</strong></th>
                                <td>
                                    First International for Consults & Training
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row"><strong>Address:</strong></th>
                                <td>
                                    Office #1, Floor #1, Building #11, Ibn Seena St #10, Al Muntazah #1
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row"><strong>City:</strong></th>
                                <td>
                                    Doha
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row"><strong>Phone No.:</strong></th>
                                <td>
                                    (+974) 4444 4444
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row"><strong>Email:</strong></th>
                                <td>
                                    info@example.com
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```